# Add additional xmlns:xsi attributes to XML element

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I have the following XML defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:container xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns0="ns0.com" xsi:schemaLocation="ns0.com ns0.xsd">
   <ns1:elementA xmlns:ns1="ns1.com" xsi:schemaLocation="ns1.com ns1.xsd"/>
   <ns2:elementB xmlns:ns2="ns2.com" xsi:schemaLocation="ns2.com ns2.xsd"/>
</ns0:container>
```

The problem is that the consuming application only takes the elements inside of the container (unfortunately with a string cutting of the container), and then the definition of the namespace xsi is missing.

I would like to add the `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` **to each sub element of the container too** - this would be a reduntant specification, but should not cause any problems.

So this is the result I would like to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:container xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns0="container.com" xsi:schemaLocation="ns0.com ns0.xsd">
   <ns1:elementA xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns1="ns1.com" xsi:schemaLocation="ns1.com ns1.xsd" />
   <ns2:elementB xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="ns2.com" xsi:schemaLocation="ns2.com ns2.xsd"/>
</ns0:container>
```

Here is my XSLT, I tried several options, but was not able to do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:ns0="ns0.com"
    xmlns:ns1="ns1.com"
    xmlns:ns2="ns2.com">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="ns0:container/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- Here I want to add the xmlns:xsi as attribute -->
            <xsl:attribute name="xsi">http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance</xsl:attribute>
            <!-- But this does not work - how should I do that? -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**How can I add additional xmlns:xsi="" to an element with XSLT?**

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but note that your `xsi:schemaLocation` attributes are wrong - the value should be _pairs_ of namespace URI and schema URL, not just the schema URL on its own, so you need e.g `xsi:schemaLocation="container.com ns0.xsd"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="ns0.com">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="ns0:container/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*/@xsi:*">
        <xsl:attribute name="other:{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Edited:

You can even simplify it as this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*/@xsi:*">
        <xsl:attribute name="other:{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think in your xml you also have a typo in declaration ns0's namespace *(xmlns:ns0="container.com")*. I think you mean *(xmlns:ns0="ns0.com")*

Comment: This works. This changes the prefix of the namespace in the container and then it uses again the xsi prefix in the sub-elements for the same namespace. Nice solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to fix the code that does string processing instead of XML processing, as I don't think you will be able to add the namespace declaration with XSLT.

All you could do is

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:container/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="../namespace::*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

but in-scope namespace nodes are copied anyway with `xsl:copy` and when serializing the result tree the serializer of the XSLT processor will not create namespace declarations if they have already been output on a parent or ancestor element.

Comment: Ok so your final answer is: Not possible with XSLT. The copy-of does not do anything in my example above...

Comment: I mentioned the `copy-of` of namespaces as it is the only way in XSLT 1.0 to create such namespace nodes. But you are right, I don't see a way with XSLT to force the serializer of the XSLT processor to output namespace declaration attributes for namespace nodes which are already defined on a parent or ancestor. So enforcing the output you want with a namespace declaration on the root and the child elements is not possible with XSLT. You would need to use a DOM API or similar allowing you to create a namespace declaration attribute.